# How to measure latency distribution

Tags: performance, statistics, monitoring, latency

I'm trying to analyze latency distribution in the system. Latencies collected in the following way: maximal observed latency per minute is measured then, if this latency is largest latency seen this day, this value is recorded. At the end of the day I have something like this:

```
[12, 15, 19, ..., 57, 120]
```

This is a time of the API calls in ms seen in one day. I need to construct some useful metric from this data but I don't know how! Obviously it wouldn't make sense if I calculate average or median from this dataset. It wouldn't represent real median or average because if max latency occurred during first minute of the day - it will be both the median and the average. I can't rely on max value because this can be an outlier caused by some rare event like network lag. This outlier wouldn't represent the code quality and wouldn't help to catch real errors.

Can you help me to build metric that makes sense from this data?

Comment: Are you trying to get some indication of an average that excludes outliers?

Comment: Exactly. I need outliers to but this is simple.

Comment: Sounds like you need some sort of [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average). You might be able to exclude a fixed number of outliers from such an average.

Comment: I need to produce single measurement from this list of numbers. This is latency numbers from one day and I'm planning to aggregate this measurements for larger time range and analyze. Yes, moving average can be used for this but at first I need to build some metric from this list of numbers.

Comment: It is probably possible to devise a way to infer parameters for a specific distribution from the running maximum you have available. Then your sole reported number could be (say) the 95th or 99th percentile of the estimated distribution. I don't know if that's a solved problem; you might be able to find out by asking on stats.stackexchange.com. It does sound like an interesting problem, which is kind of too bad, since I'm sure you don't want an _interesting_ problem.

Comment: Do you have the timestamps at which the numbers [12, 15, 19, ..., 57, 120] were recorded? I suspect that having those would make it easier to derive a formula.

Comment: It's good to have an interesting problem. At this point I decide to save top N elements of each array (one array per day for each parameter) and interpret them as points in mulitdimentional space. It is possible to cluster data for each param using knn and find outliers but this should be checked or real data first. I'm studying your proposal too, anyway it's not enough data to decide what's better or worse.

Comment: And yes, I have a timestamps.

Comment: @Lazin Clustering to find outliers doesn't seem like a valid approach, as it ignores the omitted values, which carry some information (namely that the latency was less than the most recent maximum). Those omitted values will be more and more important as the day wears on, since towards the end of the day, most values will be less than the most recent maximum.

Comment: I'l give your approach a try when I will have more data. I have data only for a few days now :(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have timestamps for the reported numbers, you can construct the likelihood function for a parametric distribution, find the maximum-likelihood parameter estimates, and then compute an appropriate quantile (0.95, 0.99, 0.999, whatever) and report that as the daily how-bad-is-it number. I say parametric distribution because I don't know how to carry this out nonparametrically.

Given the timestamps of the reported numbers, and assuming that otherwise latencies are observed once a minute, you can figure out how many observed latencies were omitted from the report; it is just the number of minutes from one reported number to the next. For each reported number x_i, there is a term p(x_i | a) in the likelihood function, where p is the probability density and a represents all the parameters (one or more). For each unreported number, there is a term P(x_i | a) in the likelihood function, where P is the cumulative distribution function and x_i is the most recently reported number; all the terms for the unreported numbers in one gap between reported numbers can be collected into a single term P(x_i | a)^n_i where n_i is the number of unreported numbers in the gap at which x_i is the left endpoint and x_{i + 1} is the right endpoint.

In summary, the likelihood function is

```
L(a) = product(p(x_i | a), i, 1, n) * product(P(x_i | a)^n_i, i, 1, n)
```

where n is number of reported numbers. It is probably more convenient to work with the logarithm of that. With L in hand, the strategy is to maximize L with respect to a, then compute a quantile for P(x | a*) where a* are the maximum-likelihood parameters, and report the quantile.

I don't know what's an appropriate distribution to assume for latency. I would start with a Weibull distribution, but you might have to try others.

There are all kinds of unstated assumptions here. I can fill in the details if there is interest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach, which is nonparametric. You can bound the empirical cumulative distribution function above and below: between x_i and x_{i + 1}, (1) it is bounded below by the fraction of values which are certainly less than or equal to x_i, and (2) it is bounded above by the fraction of values which are certainly greater than x_i.

These bounds are probably very loose; inverting the empirical c.d.f. will lead to very wide bounds on the quantiles -- this implies that your boundary for what constitutes an "outlier" will be known only within a relatively wide range. You might make a simplifying assumption, such as assuming the c.d.f. is piecewise linear between x_i and x_{i + 1}, in order to get point values.

(1) is just the total number of values (both reported and omitted) before x_{i + 1} was observed, divided by the total number of values all day. (2) is just 1 minus (the number of reported values after x_i (since those are the only ones which we know for sure are greater than x_i), divided by the total number of values all day).

EDIT: corrected (2).